# Nginx proxy manager with docker swarm could not reach

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment

I have a problem deploying nginx on the server using docker swarm.

**what i try to do?**

I am trying to transfer a request when the client called my DNS name `https://powersolution.digital/`  to  the NGINX proxy manager on port 81

---

**How i try to do it?**

I deployed it using `docker stack deploy -c ymlFile stackName` after checking if the service deployed without any problem and checking the logs.

I can reach the site if I try to access it using an IP address and port 81 **eg: 125.8.1.10:81**.

but after login and set the follwoing configuration

[image]

When I tried to reach the site using the domain name I got **connection time out**, also I tried to replace the IP address with `service name` like the following image, but I had the same result.

[image]

Also I can't access any other service also throw the **nginx proxy manager**

The compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  maneger-app-service:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 90:80
      - 81:81
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - acc_web
networks:
  acc_web:
    external: true
```

**Note: I tried the above solution with `docker compose -f ymlfile up` and worked without any problem**